# How to set location variable by using useState()?

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, use-state

When I try to find current location of the user and try to get `latitude` and `longitude` values, with `useState` I cannot set the location. But I can obtain the values by

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
                console.log(latitude)
}
```

but I cannot use useState like this:

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                setLocation(position.coords)  // logs: null
}
```

Maybe the construction of useState() is not correct, but I couldn't find a working way by searching forums. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of using `position.coords` directly inside `setLocation` try to destructure what all all you want and then call `setLocation`.

Comment: @Gnanavel I want to take only latitude and longitude values, but when I log it again gives null